# Odd cancan issue... works on development machine, but not the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

My ability model for cancan has been working well for 6+ months now. One of the controllers that has been around all that time is the QuestionsController. I recently added another controller, model and index page. The controller name is QuestionsBasicsController. In my ability model i have:

```
if user.permission >= 8 # admin
  can :manage, [Question, QuestionsBasic]
end
```

At the top of QuestionsController and QuestionsBasicsController i have:

```
load_and_authorize_resource
```

I am able to access the index page for both QuestionsController and QuestionsBasicsController on my development machine. After I uploaded the ability model to my server i restarted the server. I can access the index page for Question but not for QuestionsBasic on my server. On my development machine i have ruby 1.9.2 while on my server i have 1.8.7. Could it be the Ruby version difference?

UPDATE: for what it is worth names of models that begin with the name of another model cause a problem,... at least with the way I have constructed my ability model. In addition, I recently found another model name that worked fine but for CanCan. I think it may have been a reserved word but am not positive on that. When I changed the name of the model, controller, route and code to a new name it passed CanCan. No reflection on CanCan though... I think it is AWESOME, AWESOME, AWESOME! Thanks, Ryan Bates!

Comment: I've run into a couple of weird syntax things with CanCan in the past.  Have you tried breaking this one "can" statement into two separate "can" statements, one for each model?  Also, does one model inherit form the other?  A long time ago, I ran into something where CanCan crapped out on classes that had inheritance relationships.  If memory serves, I had to pass in .new instances for CanCan to get it right.

Comment: thanks. +1 good information. one doesn't inherit from the other. will try separating the two statements. The weird thing is, I can't figure out why it works in development, but not in production.

Comment: Your Ruby version hypotheses is definitely a possibility.  I took a quick comparison glance at the changes from 1.8 to 1.9 (http://www.davidflanagan.com/2007/08/changes-between-ruby-18-and-ruby-19.html) and the CanCan source, specifically rules.rb.  There seem to be some points of overlap, especially ranges.  Changes were made to include?() in 1.9 which is used to parse multiple subjects/classes in the CanCan rule generator.  That might be the source of the issue.  Hard to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

agree with dleatham, try splitting your original statement into 2 lines:

```
if user.permission >= 8 # admin
  can :manage, Question
  can :manage, QuestionsBasic
end
```